# Обработка try except в android

Tags: android, delphi, исключения, delphi-xe8

Всем знакомый обработчик ошибок.
Суть кода - это попробовать подключиться к фтп. И если нет подключения, то под win срабатывает как по учебнику.
А вод под Android приводит к полному вылетанию.
Происходит именно на строчке "idftp1.connect"
Что может быть не так?

```
procedure TForm.Memo1Click(Sender: TObject);

procedure conn; // советовали загнать соединение в отдельную процедуру - легче не стало
Begin
  idftp1.connect;
End;

begin
  if idftp1.Connected = false then         // на связи ли сервак?
  try                                      // если нет пробуем соединиться
    conn;
    servstat.Text := 'сервер на связи';
    servstat.FontColor := TAlphaColorRec.green;
    send.Enabled := true;
  except
    //on E: EConvertError do                     // ошибка соединения
  begin
    servstat.FontColor := TAlphaColorRec.Red
  end;
```

Comment: А версия Андроида какая? Вот в этом топике говорят, что не со всякой версией можно эксепшены обрабатывать: [XE7 Try-Except not working on Android 6.0+ Marshmallow](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=153838)

Comment: Вот оно что. Тестовый девайс действительно с 6.0.1, а второй с4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, вы запускаете приложение на не поддерживаемой версии Android.

Delphi XE8 [официально поддерживает](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/PlatformStatus/en/Main_Page) следующие версии:

```
Android 5
Android 4.4
Android 4.1.x, 4.2.x, 4.3.x
Android 4.0.3, 4.0.4
```

Корректная работа на остальных версиях, не гарантируется.

Comment: Всё. Проблема решена, спасибо. Переходим на Берлин)